# Use another property from json in a custom JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Assume the following JSON:

```json
{
  "channel": "751853588527054938"
  "message": "751853745758928908"
}
```

And the following part of code:

```cs
        [JsonConverter(typeof(TextChannelConverter))]
        [JsonProperty("channel")]
        public ITextChannel Channel;

        [JsonConverter(typeof(UserMessageConverter))]
        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public IUserMessage Message;
```

What I'm trying to do is, I want to have a custom converter for deserealization for both of these types, but the problem is that, I can't get a message if I only have its ID, I also need to know the channel ID to do so (More precisesly, the message is retrieved using ITextChannel#GetMessageAsync(ulong id)). Is there a way to access the ID of the channel or even the channel object in UserMessageConverter?

I have tried loading the entire JSON from the reader

```cs
    class UserMessageConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(IUserMessage);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jobj = JObject.Load(reader);
            return null;
        }
```

But it issues an exception:

```cs
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: Integer. Path 'message', line 1, position 75.
```

For reference, the code of TextChannelConverter:

```cs
        class TextChannelConverter : JsonConverter
        {
        public override bool CanWrite => false;
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(ITextChannel);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.Value == null)
                return null;

            ulong channelid = ulong.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());

            return Essentials.FireLands.GetChannel(channelid);
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be a weird way to use `JsonConverter`. Why wouldn't you just deserialize to string, which is what it is... then after it's deserialized process the data. It looks like you are trying to kill 2 birds with 1 stone.. but why? Chances are you are going to need to do I/O bound operations in `ReadJson` and `ReadJson` isn't asynchronous so it's going to block.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the properties is dependent on the other, then you would need to make a single `JsonConverter` that handles the parent object, rather than two separate converters for each of the child properties.

You didn't say what class contains the `Channel` and `Message` properties in your model, so I'll just call it `Chat` for sake of example.

So you would have:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ChatConverter))]
class Chat
{    
    public ITextChannel Channel { get; set; }
    public IUserMessage Message { get; set; }
}
```

And then your converter might look something like this:

```
class ChatConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Chat);
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.Value == null)
            return null;

        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        ulong channelId = (ulong)obj["channel"];
        ulong messageId = (ulong)obj["message"];

        ITextChannel channel = Essentials.FireLands.GetChannel(channelId);
        IUserMessage = channel.GetMessageAsync(messageId).Result;

        return new Chat { Channel = channel, Message = message };
    }
}
```